# Can't succesfully run juju bootstrap

Tags: juju

What should i do to correct this error?
ERROR Could not find any Cobbler systems marked as available and configured for network boot.

Answer (score 1):

login to the cobbler admin pages.

For each system that you want to manage, and click the Management tab in the system properties page.

Choose the Orchestra-Juju-Available entry and click the Add button (The right hand arrow, that moves the item into the right hand item list)

Now make sure that Nework boot is checked on the main system properties page.

Click save.

Now, when you run juju bootstrap, it will work with the hosts that you have marked in this way.